# Is it possible to print a text from a URL into a image, in real time?

Tags: image-processing

I want to make a coupon and i already have the name or email address of the user, i want to generate the link to a image (the coupon) plus the name and/or email so it's visible into the coupon.

This is for personalization and being able to control the coupons.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but this is an English language site.  (If someone is willing to translate, I'll consider reopening.  Just @message me.)

Comment: @BilltheLizard: I am guessing it, but it looks like the OP wants to know how to create images with text in them (like an email) in real time (like as a response to an HTTP request).

Comment: @Bill i've translated the question.

Comment: @Matias, @abhin4v: Thanks guys.  Now hopefully @Pablo can use any answers that he gets.

Comment: @Matias
Thanks for doing the translation, the Google translator is not ta precise technical or programming issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this tutorial will help: [Serving Dynamic Images with Python CGI and Graphics Libraries](http://lost-theory.org/python/dynamicimg.html)

Comment: Thanks I will read it carefully and see if I can do what I want.
I thank the time to answer.